# SOLVED: Query a cell and return multiple results as string in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a worksheet that calculates "begin date" (Column E) and "end date" (Column F) of an activity, then compares it to the "Ideal no. of days" (Cell H1) to decide if the process faced a delay.

Examples:

Activity 1 - Took 13 days, which 6 days more than ideal, and is therefore LATE.

Activity 2 - Took 4 days, which is less than ideal period, and therefore is NOT LATE.

How can I get both results in just one cell?

Ideal state would be:

Activity 1 output - LATE (-6)

Activity 2 output - NOT LATE (3) / ON-TIME

[How it looks on google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYxpG.png)

Edit: Added formula currently in use. It can also be seen on the screenshot.

=IF(G4>7, "LATE", "NOT LATE")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might get a better response to your question if you post your formula, the current result, and the desired result as text in the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the post to add the formula I am currently using. My objective is to merge columns H & I into one.

Comment: Formula in H4: =IF(I4<0,CONCAT("LATE (",I4,")"),CONCAT("NOT LATE (",I4,") / ON-TIME"))

Comment: Thank you. Which cell did you put the formula in? I tried with Cell J, but it returned an error - Wrong number of arguments to CONCAT. Expected 2, received 3.

Comment: Here's a link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12svjmZRlvhDOWkmdhcQexErzjijuYQ3izSntjED-bSk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Formula as specified goes in H4.

Comment: O wait this is google sheets? I thought it was Excel. Try this (in H4): =IF(I4<0, "LATE (" & I4 & ")", "NOT LATE (" & I4 & ") / ON-TIME")

Answer (score 1):

I added a new sheet ("Erik Help"). In that sheet, I removed all of your individual formulas from G4:H and replaced them with one array formula in G3 and one array formula in H3. Each of these formulas will produce the header and all column results for their respective ranges.

The G3 formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"Time Taken";IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(E4:E))+NOT(ISNUMBER(F4:F)),,F4:F-E4:E)})`

The H3 formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"Delay Status";IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(F4:F)),IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(E4:E)),,"IN PROGRESS"),IFS(F4:F-E4:E>7,"LATE (",TRUE,"ON TIME (")&H1-(F4:F-E4:E)&")")})`

These formulas may seem "long" to some. They're really not, but they are longer than one might expect because they control for several likely error scenarios.

Here, I used the ampersand symbol for concatenation of the final "phrases" in H4:H.

Comment: Thank you, Erik. This helped solve the problem and I have managed to use it successfully. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Would you take a moment and mark my post as "Best Answer"? This allows contributors to see from the main listings page which issues are already fully resolved; and it helps future site visitors like yourself quickly find the answers most relevant to their own searches and needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Formula in Cell H8:

IF($G8>$H$1, CONCATENATE("LATE ", SUM($G8-$H$1)), CONCATENATE("NOT LATE ", 0))

I also updated your spreasheet Col K `GoodJuJu`and cell H8

[image]

Comment: Thank you, GoodJuJu for taking time to update it on the sheet. 
Your solution is helpful,  and I really appreciate the support! Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution using Excel 365,

suppose you have given a name to the ideal date called **Ideal_Days**

you can try the following in cell `H4` and drag it down to apply across:

```
=LET(x,Ideal_Days-G4,IF(x<0,"LATE ("&x&")","NOT LATE ("&x&")"))
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Thank you, I am using google sheets. While Erik's solution worked for me, I will try yours out as well. Really appreciate your help!